# Отображение метаданных в запросе GET. WordPress REST API

Tags: php, wordpress, rest

Есть действующий сайт на WordPress и в нём хранятся некоторые записи пользовательского типа. Мне необходимо получать с помощью REST некую информацию из этих записей. Для этого я добавил в коде следующую строку:

```
add_post_meta($order['id'], "order_place_id", $place_id, true);
```

Она вроде как должна позволить получать нужные данные. Но при чтении json-файла, который возвращает GET-запрос, у всех записей в этом поле находится `null`. Попробовав создать новую запись ПОСЛЕ добавления этой строки обнаружил, что новая запись имеет нужное значение в этом поле (не `null`). Из чего сделал вывод, что добавленный код вносит изменения только для новых записей, а существующие не меняет. **Однако, мне нужно получать информацию и из существующих. Как это сделать?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Для этого я добавил в коде следующую строку:
>
> ```
> add_post_meta($order['id'], "order_place_id", $place_id, true);
> ```
>
> Она вроде как должна позволить получать нужные данные.

Нет, эта  функция не *получает*, а *добавляет* данные в произвольные поля См. https://wp-kama.ru/function/add_post_meta.

Для получения данных из произвольных полей выбирай подходящую функцию начинающуюся на "**get**_": https://wp-kama.ru/function-cat/proizvolnyie-polya

Comment: Похоже, меня интересует функция get_post_meta. По всей видимости, я ещё и в неправильном месте использовал функцию. Я писал её в функции добавления записи в БД. Скажите, а где правильнее будет использовать функцию get_post_meta для возвращения этих данных как результат get-запроса?

Comment: Не понятно что значит "где".. Там где тебе нужно.. И см ещё get_post_custom, сравни разницу с get_post_meta.

Comment: А да, тебе же РЕСТ-АПИ... см https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/global-parameters/#_fields

Comment: Но у меня пользовательский тип. То есть, я обращаюсь не по ../wp/v2/posts, а к примеру ../wp/v2/orders.

Comment: Я хочу увидеть нужные мне произвольные поля в программе Postman, обращаясь по запросу .../wp-json/v2/orders. Сделав, как написано в вопросе, получаю лишь id_place: null - для записей ДО добавления строчки из вопроса и id_place: какое-то значение - для записей ПОСЛЕ добавления строки из вопроса.

Comment: Не очень понимаю... Чтобы их увидеть (получить) они должны существовать. Существовать не просо название полей, а и их значения. ПП - это не глобальные данные, а у конкретного поста (кастомного в тч) свои https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F